# Python Pandas: Lookup value in df1 based on value in df2, but strike off df1 row for next iteration

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes. I need to match a value from df1 in df2 and capture a value from the same row in df2. The captured value is unique and can only be shown once in the output.

Grossly simplified data:

df1:

```
    Name    ID
0   Bob      1
1   Bob      2
2   Bob      3
3   Sam      4
4   Sam      5
5   Jon      6
6   Bob      7
```

df2:

```
    Name
0   Sam
1   Bob
2   Sam
3   Bob
4   Bob
5   Bob
6   Jon
```

Desired output:

```
    Name    ID
0   Sam      4
1   Bob      1
2   Sam      5
3   Bob      2
4   Bob      3
5   Bob      7
6   Jon      6
```

`df = pandas.merge(df1, df2, on="Name")`

produces this:

```
Unnamed: 0_x Name  ID  Unnamed: 0_y
0              0  Bob   1             1
1              0  Bob   1             3
2              0  Bob   1             4
3              0  Bob   1             5
4              1  Bob   2             1
5              1  Bob   2             3
6              1  Bob   2             4
7              1  Bob   2             5
8              2  Bob   3             1
9              2  Bob   3             3
10             2  Bob   3             4
11             2  Bob   3             5
12             3  Sam   4             0
13             3  Sam   4             2
14             4  Sam   5             0
15             4  Sam   5             2
16             5  Jon   6             6
17             6  Bob   7             1
18             6  Bob   7             3
19             6  Bob   7             4
20             6  Bob   7             5
```

What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: have you tried adding the `how=` that will dictate how the merge/join will act and not produce x, y columns?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temporary column to both dataframes to identify the occurrence of each name:

```
out = (df2.assign(occ=df2.groupby('Name').cumcount())
          .merge(df1.assign(occ=df1.groupby('Name').cumcount()), on=['Name', 'occ'])
          .drop(columns='occ'))
print(out)

# Output
  Name  ID
0  Sam   4
1  Bob   1
2  Sam   5
3  Bob   2
4  Bob   3
5  Bob   7
6  Jon   6
```